# Can't get value of input in Javascript outside the function

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input with id `input`. I have different functions to calculate sin, cos and tan in js. I try this which working smoothly.

```js
function sin() {
    var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
    sine = Math.sin(value);
    document.getElementById('answers').value= sine;}
    
function cos() {
    var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
    cose = Math.cos(value);
    document.getElementById('answers').value = cose;
}
function tan() {
    var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
    tang = Math.tan(value);
    document.getElementById('answers').value = tang;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<button onclick="sin()">Sin</button>
<button onclick="sin()">cos</button>
<button onclick="sin()">tan</button>
<input id="answers"/>
```

When I try this to make code small it does not work.

```js
var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
function sin() {   
    sine = Math.sin(value);
    document.getElementById('answers').value= sine;}
    
function cos() {
    cose = Math.cos(value);
    document.getElementById('answers').value = cose;
}
function tan() {
    tang = Math.tan(value);
    document.getElementById('answers').value = tang;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<button onclick="sin()">Sin</button>
<button onclick="sin()">cos</button>
<button onclick="sin()">tan</button>
<input id="answers"/>
```

Any suggestion should be helpful

Comment: You are getting the value of the input _immediately_ on load, and only once.  You need to get the value when the button is clicked.  I'd probably put the "get value" into a function, and call it within the various calculation functions.  Additionally, I'd probably make it a _single_ calc function, with a switch to determine _which_ calculation it should do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the value of the input *immediately* on load, and only once.  You need to get the value when the button is clicked.  I'd probably put the "get value" into a function, and call it within the various calculation functions.  Additionally, I'd probably make it a *single* calc function, with a switch to determine *which* calculation it should do.

This feels DRY-er.

This could be improved even further if you wanted, by using javascript [event binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), rather than hard-coding the `onclick` event into each element.

```js
// single function, accepts a "type" argument
function calc(type) {
  // get the value of the input when the button is clicked
  const value = document.getElementById('input').value;
  // declare the result
  let result = 0;
  switch (type) {
    case 'sin':
      result = Math.sin(value);
      break;
    case 'cos':
      result = Math.cos(value);
      break;
    case 'tan':
      result = Math.tan(value);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  // show the result in the input
  document.getElementById('answers').value = result;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button onclick="calc('sin')">Sin</button>
<button onclick="calc('cos')">cos</button>
<button onclick="calc('tan')">tan</button>
<input id="answers" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why it happens? It's because of the priority of loading `DOM`, first the javascript file load, then did not find any `input` tag, because it will load afterward.

when you create a `function`, it added to the `window` object, and when you call it onclick of a tag, because the DOM is loaded then it's value is accessible.

To access to correct result, you can use one of bellows.

1) If put all `javascript` into this structure, it will works.

```
window.onload = function(){
  //Your code
}
```

2) if you put your `script` tag bellow of `input` tag